# Splitting a long table in more than one page

Tags: tables

I am doing tables with `table` enviorment, but it doesnt allow tables to split into pages. So, what enviorment can I use to do this? (could you please write the same table - wrriten in the code below - with this new enviorment?)

And there's a few more details: In my code (below), there's a \listoftables with specific details (for instance, the title is not the default), so I'd like to maintain the same formatation in respect to the list of tables IF the use of a new enviorment changes it.

One last thing: The title of the table, as written in the code, should be unique and centered. Also, I have to lable the table.

This post could be split in a several ones (because there's could be several issues), but the solutions may conflict. Nevertheless, if I have to I will post other topics with only one specific issue. Thank you

CODE:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
   \usepackage{float}
   \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %CODE
   \usepackage{uarial}% FOR
   \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}% ARIAL FONT

   \usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
   \parindent=1.5cm

   \usepackage{tocloft}
   \renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Tabela }
   \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %dots for sections


   \usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage{footnotebackref}


   \begin{document}
       \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\normalsize\hspace{6.5cm}LISTA DE                         TABELAS}
    \listoftables
    \newpage
    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT 

    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT \ref{table1}
\begin{table}[H]     
    \begin{center}  
        \caption{Lista dos amortecimentos mínimos para cada ponto de operação em relação diferentes sistemas de controle operando}
        \label{table1}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline  Point & Data1  & Data2 & Data3 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 1& 15.59  & 40.80 & 28.19 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 2& 15.59 & 38.83 &  27.98 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 3& 15.63 & 41.48 &  27.71 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 4& 15.77 & 36.19 &  29.06\\ 
                \hline Ponto 5& 15.71 & 41.47 &  27.26\\ 
                \hline Ponto 6& 15.92 & 36.70 &  27.57\\ 
                \hline Ponto 7& 16.13 & 40.18 &  28.34\\ 
                \hline Ponto 8& 16.21 & 35.80 &  27.34\\ 
                \hline Ponto 9& 15.75 & 40.95 &  27.08\\ 
                \hline Ponto 10& 15.89& 35.21 &  29.18\\ 
                \hline Ponto 11& 16.20 & 33.60 & 29.30 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 12& 15.81 & 40.36 & 26.84 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 13& 16.89 & 34.40 & 26.87 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 14& 18.16 & 43.44 & 34.15 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 15& 23.74 & 37.72 & 30.89 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 16& 17.10 & 38.15 & 28.71 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 17& 19.51 & 30.68 & 25.64 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 18& 15.53 & 26.82 & 23.00 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 19& 12.56 & 34.74 & 26.83 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 20& 19.33 & 37.94 & 31.92 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 21& 20.07 & 37.21 & 35.49 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 22& 15.62 & 38.39 & 28.66 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 23& 15.67 & 37.94 & 25.93 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 24& 15.72 & 37.75 & 25.61 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 25& 15.76 & 37.99 & 25.41 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 26& 15.69 & 31.47 & 26.37 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 27& 17.35 & 29.22 & 25.28 \\ 
                \hline 
            \end{tabular} 
            \end{center}
        \footnotesize{Fonte: Autoria própria (2016).} 
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: please don't use float (table environment) nor center environment and use [longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) and [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using a `longtable` environment, as is done in the following modified (and simplified/shortened) version of your code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable} % <---- new
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{helvet} % I don't have 'uarial' package
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\parindent=1.5cm

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Tabela }
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %dots for sections
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LISTA DE TABELAS}


%\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{footnotebackref}


\begin{document}
\listoftables

\newpage

\tablename~\ref{tab:amortecimentos}

\begin{longtable}{|l|c|c|c|}
\caption[Lista dos amortecimentos mínimos]{Lista dos amortecimentos mínimos para cada ponto de operação em relação diferentes sistemas de controle operando}\label{tab:amortecimentos}\\
\hline  Point & Data1 & Data2 & Data3 \\ 
\endhead
\hline
\endlastfoot
\hline Ponto 1& 15.59  & 40.80 & 28.19 \\ 
\hline Ponto 2& 15.59 & 38.83 &  27.98 \\ 
\hline Ponto 3& 15.63 & 41.48 &  27.71 \\ 
\hline Ponto 4& 15.77 & 36.19 &  29.06\\ 
\hline Ponto 5& 15.71 & 41.47 &  27.26\\ 
\hline Ponto 6& 15.92 & 36.70 &  27.57\\ 
\hline Ponto 7& 16.13 & 40.18 &  28.34\\ 
\hline Ponto 8& 16.21 & 35.80 &  27.34\\ 
\hline Ponto 9& 15.75 & 40.95 &  27.08\\ 
\hline Ponto 10& 15.89& 35.21 &  29.18\\ 
\hline Ponto 11& 16.20 & 33.60 & 29.30 \\ 
\hline Ponto 12& 15.81 & 40.36 & 26.84 \\ 
\hline Ponto 13& 16.89 & 34.40 & 26.87 \\ 
\hline Ponto 14& 18.16 & 43.44 & 34.15 \\ 
\hline Ponto 15& 23.74 & 37.72 & 30.89 \\ 
\hline Ponto 16& 17.10 & 38.15 & 28.71 \\ 
\hline Ponto 17& 19.51 & 30.68 & 25.64 \\ 
\hline Ponto 18& 15.53 & 26.82 & 23.00 \\ 
\hline Ponto 19& 12.56 & 34.74 & 26.83 \\ 
\hline Ponto 20& 19.33 & 37.94 & 31.92 \\ 
\hline Ponto 21& 20.07 & 37.21 & 35.49 \\ 
\hline Ponto 22& 15.62 & 38.39 & 28.66 \\ 
\hline Ponto 23& 15.67 & 37.94 & 25.93 \\ 
\hline Ponto 24& 15.72 & 37.75 & 25.61 \\ 
\hline Ponto 25& 15.76 & 37.99 & 25.41 \\ 
\hline Ponto 26& 15.69 & 31.47 & 26.37 \\ 
\hline Ponto 27& 17.35 & 29.22 & 25.28 \\  
\end{longtable}
\footnotesize{Fonte: Autoria própria (2016).}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for you answer but with this solution the title of the table it's in the two pages that the table are occupying (should be only one). And the table font: `\footnotesize{Fonte: Autoria própria (2016).}` is centered (should be flush left)

Comment: I'm already using this `longtable` enviorment and it's working all right, but there's is an issue for tables that are larger than text width. I used to use `\resizebox`for table enviorment but, in the `longtable` enviorment, it doesnt work. I believe that is the only issue with this transition of enviorments.

Comment: @gustavoreche - I've modified the code so that `\footnotesize{Fonte: Autoria própria (2016).}` no longer is inside the `longtable`.